# Javascript change color on keyup and keydown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to follow the example that I saw here http://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/gFkY2/.  However for me it is not working. When I run my app and i start typing in the textbox nothing is happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtBrandFooter").keydown(function() {
    text_changed();
  });

  $("#txtBrandFooter").keyup(function() {
    $("#txtBrandFooter").css("background-color", "pink");
  });
});

function text_changed() {
  $("#txtBrandFooter").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

```html
<%-- <asp:TextBox  CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtBrandFooter" runat="server" />--%>
<input class="gridTextbox" id="txtBrandFooter" type="text" name="brand" value="" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I placed the code in your question in to an executable snippet where it works absolutely fine. Check the console for errors, and ensure you've included jQuery and your JS code in the correct places.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have included JQuery and JS in the correct place and I don't see anything in the console that could explain why it is not working. What else could it be?

Comment: The alternative would be that there is no `#txtBrandFooter` element in the DOM when the page loads, or you've spelled it incorrectly in your local version

Comment: Is the element in your working copy the ASP.Net TextBox control? If so, that's the problem. When you use `runat="server"` ASP will dynamically change the `ID` of the element at runtime, so `#txtBrandFooter` will not exist in the client HTML. You need to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the control, or use the `txtBrandFooter.ClientId` property to select the element in your JS.

Comment: I figured out my error thanks for all your help. I put both functions inside a other function like this        $(function () {       $(document).ready(function () {  for some reason that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtBrandFooter").keydown(function() {
    text_changed();
  });

  $("#txtBrandFooter").keyup(function() {
    $("#txtBrandFooter").css("background-color", "pink");
  });
});

function text_changed() {
  $("#txtBrandFooter").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

```html
<input class="gridTextbox" id="txtBrandFooter" type="text" name="brand" value="" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just delete asp.net control textbox